# Creating a new Qapplication from Qapplication event loop

Tags: python, qt, pyqt, multiprocessing, qapplication

I have rewritten the question so that it is more clear.

In my code I created a QApplication, connected a slot to the application using QTimer.singleShot(), then executed my application.

Now in this slot I want to create another QApplication in another process, I used multiprocessing.Process Class and from inside the process I try to start another QApplication and execute it, but I have an error because an event loop is already running!, I know I can't run two event loops but I am running the new QApplication in another process so it should run.

I know this is not a common implementation but it would be much easier to get this running in my case.

Here is a code example:
The error I get is "QCoreApplication::exec: The event loop is already running"

```
import multiprocessing
from PyQt4 import QtCore,QtGui

def first_app_slot():
    mProcess = multiprocessing.Process(target = run_another_app)
    mProcess.start()
    mProcess.join()

def run_another_app():
    second_app = QtGui.QApplication([])
    second_app.exec_()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    first_app = QtGui.QApplication([])
    QtCore.QTimer.singleShot(0,first_app_slot)
    first_app.exec_()
```

Comment: please post your code !

Comment: I have no idea what you're trying to do, what is erroring, etc. Please make this question useful for others - we can't read your mind.

Comment: Sorry for this, I have rewritten the question, Thanks for your feedback.

Comment: This looks like an [XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info/). Please explain your *real* problem, rather than what you think is a solution to it. It's very likely there are much better ways to achieve what you want.

Comment: Actually the problem is that I am stuck in this setup, I need to start a new QApplication from another QApplication event loop, so the solution I thought of was to start the other QApplication in another process but as you see it is not working.

Comment: @YahiaKhalid. But **why** do you think you need to do this? What is the second application for? Does the first application need to comminucate with the second one? Why do you need a separate process for it? If the other process doesn't need an event-loop, what's the point in creating a `QApplication` for it?

Answer (score 0):

A few problems

1. In your code, you're not calling any of the multiprocessing code (maybe a typo)?
2. Don't create the first `QApplication` in the global scope, put it inside a function.  Before creating a new process, `multiprocessing` will copy the global state to the new process, which includes `first_app` in this case.

Ex.

```
def main():
    first_app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    ...

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: Yes it was a typo sorry for this, I tried the solution you proposed but it is not working, I guess the problem is that the new process is created as a child process from the QApp or something, so even if the application reference (first_app) was deleted, The QApp still lives in the process and for example could be got using QCoreApplication.instance(), I want this process to run completely independent of the QApp.

Comment: I know the logic solution for my case would be to create the processes first then start the QApp each one in his process, but for some reason I am stuck in my case.